# How to test Bitcoin's RPC interface?

Tags: json-rpc

I can't find any tool to test RPC interface. I am looking for something like Postman (Chrome extenstion). I would like to send request (with login and password) and see their responses in JSON.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar as well. Or at the very least, a tutorial

Comment: Not to worry. Found what I needed here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29, and here: https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc

Answer (score 2):

My favorate tool to test an API endpoint is always `curl`

```
curl --user user --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

source: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#Command_line_.28cURL.29